# What is the command to find the read/write permissions for a single file?

Tags: files, permissions, ls

I know that `ls -l` lists the permissions of every file in a directory but what is the command if I want to see the permissions of just a specific file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the info provided by `ls -l` for a single file or folder, use the `-d` option and specify the file:

```
ls -ld filename
```

Answer (score 6):

To just get the mode:

```
stat -c %a file
```

(where `file` can also be a directory).

Note: this is with the `stat` command from the GNU Coreutils. Otherwise the solution is system dependent.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to do something depending on the file permission then in some cases you can consider simple `test` (aka `[` or `[[`) conditional statement:

- `-r` file exists and read permission is granted
- `-w` file exists and write permission is granted
- `-x` exists and execute permission is granted

For example:

```
[ -w file ] && echo foo >> file
```

Answer (score 1):

As "permissions" doesn't just cover octal unix permissions on modern Linux systems, I'd like to elaborate a little:

Apart from `stat -c %a file` @vinc17 suggested, there's `stat -c %C file` for the SELinux context on RHEL Systems, and `getfacl file` for volumes using ACLs.

`namei -m /path/to/file` might be helpful for finding out all octal permissions leading down the path to the file, as wrong permissions on the parent directories can inhibit access.